# React-Admin Unit Test Failing

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, testing-library

I have this unit test in my React-Admin app:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { AdminContext } from 'react-admin';

test('render appl', async () => {
  render(
    <AdminContext>
      <App />  
    </AdminContext>
  )
  const linkElement = await 
    screen.findByText(/The page is loading, just a moment please/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

It was working for a while, then stopped working suddenly the other day with this error:

```
FAIL src/App.test.js (16.248 s)
  ● render app
    Unable to find an element 
      with the text: /The page is loading, just a moment please/i. 
    This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. 
    In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to 
      make your matcher more flexible.
    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="MuiScopedCssBaseline-root css-vv3oxb-MuiScopedCssBaseline-root"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
      11 |     </AdminContext>
      12 |   )
    > 13 |   const linkElement = await 
            screen.findByText(/The page is loading, just a moment please/i);
         |                                    ^
      14 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      15 | });
      16 |
      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:166:27)
      at findByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:86:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:13:36)
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
```

Any idea why or how to resolve this?

I did recently upgrade from React-Admin 4.6 to 4.8. I've been looking for something that perhaps changed between those versions that broke this test - but haven't found anything yet to explain it. The same message still resides in the framework [code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/6ee8d71470d8d1748678aef77c3f498cdf715ec1/packages/ra-language-english/src/index.ts#L106).

The testing-library versions I'm using are:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
```

Comment: "then stopped working suddenly" – have you tried checking out an old commit to see what changed?

Comment: @Leland yes, definitely. I did recently change from React-Admin 4.6 to 4.8. I'm thinking maybe something changed between those versions to break this test - but I haven't yet found anything in the source that would explain it. That same loading text still exists in the framework source.

Comment: If you're looking for loading text in the test, it may be that the test is flaky; i.e. sometimes it succeeds and sometimes does not.